# Is there a way to get numpy to import only float values?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy

I have a large excel data sheet that I import using pandas. I need to calculate things like standard deviation etc. When I convert the file to numpy, it also imports the string values. Is there a way for the numpy array to only have float values?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as ny
a = pd.read_excel('Prior Example.xlsm', 'Security Levels Raw')
c = a.to_numpy()

d = ny.std(c)
```

Comment: What's the dtypes of the dataframe? Are some columns float and others object (strings)?

Comment: Yes the first two columns are strings and the rest are float.

Comment: Then tell pandas the export only the float columns to numpy

Comment: How do I do that

Comment: Read pandas docs about selecting columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `converters` argument (also exists for `pd.read_excel`). Though really I'd just convert afterwards:

#### `test.csv`

```
number1,number2
1,foo
2,bar
3,4
1,4
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_numbers(s):
    return pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters={'number2': convert_numbers})
display(df)
df.dtypes
```

#### Output:

```
#   number1  number2
#0        1      NaN
#1        2      NaN
#2        3      4.0
#3        1      4.0

#number1      int64
#number2    float64
#dtype: object
```

Comment: He's talking about Excel, not CSV

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux fair. Lucikly that reader has the same argument, so it will still work. Just easier to give a mcve with .csv